# Setting TextView's text as non-English text received from JSON response

Tags: android, textview

I'm getting back names of (Foursquare) venues from a server call where the names of the venues returned can be in English or non-English.

Assume the venue name is in a JSON object as follows:

```
{...
 "name":"venue name which can be in any language"
...}
```

I'm creating a JSONObject from this response and then pulling out the name of the venue as follows:

```
String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
```

Lastly, I'm setting the TextView's text to show the name of the venue as follows:

```
myTextView.setText(name);
```

I'm finding however for Arabic names that where the Arabic characters are joined in the original JSON object (as they should be), the characters that show in the app (i.e. in the TextView) are disjoint. (I'm not too familiar with other languages so can't really tell if they're showing incorrectly too.)

Is there something additional I should be doing to pull out non-English names correctly from the JSON object and setting it as the text of a TextView, or is it down to the phone to decide how the text will be displayed?

> **Edit:** I've tried parsing the server response (as suggested by @bbedward) explicitly specifying the content encoding as UTF-8 as follows...

```
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
String responseMessage = EntityUtils.toString(myHttpEntity, "UTF-8");
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseMessage);
```

> ... but still no joy. (Arabic characters appear, as before, disjoint in words where they should be joint up.) Could it be a phone thing or is there something extra needing to be done myself to get the words/characters to show proper in non-English languages? Perhaps the server needs to explicitly specify a "Content-Type" header with value "UTF-8"?

Comment: This is a shot in the dark, but you're probably not getting your json string in UTF-8. If this is the case, I'll post an answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer anyway, I'm *guessing* you aren't getting your json in UTF-8 as i had a similar problem, I believe json won't come any other way.

**Complete Example**

*The only things to concern yourself with this is setting the encoding for the InputStreamReader and creating the JSONObject*

```
private DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://myjsonurl.com/search?type=json");
    // Depending on your web service
    httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        try
        {
            String result = null;
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);           
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "utf-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            JSONObject myJObject = new JSONObject(sb.toString();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}catch(Exception none){}
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response bbedward. Was hoping that would do it but unfortunately no joy. See the "Edit" at the bottom of my question. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

add this line when you connect to mysql:

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8', $con);
```

ex:

```
$con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
mysql_set_charset('utf8', $con);
mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
```

Comment: So you're saying it's a server-side issue rather than a client-side issue?